# Line reader fails depending on buffer size

Tags: java, junit, reader

I need to read an input stream line by line. A line is considered to be terminated only by CRLF, but not by a single CR or LF. This rules out `BufferedReader`'s `readLine()` and had me implement my own solution:

```java
final class LineReader
{
    private final Reader reader;
    private final char[] buffer;
    private final Queue<String> lines = new LinkedList<>();
    private StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
    private boolean cr = false;

    LineReader(final Reader reader, final int bufferSize)
    {
        this.reader = reader;
        buffer = new char[bufferSize];
    }

    String readLine() throws IOException
    {
        while (lines.peek() == null)
        {
            final int read = reader.read(buffer);
            if (read == - 1)
            {
                if (line == null)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                // Reached EOF. Return the last line.
                lines.add(line.toString());
                line = null;
                continue;
            }

            // Split the buffer by line.
            int offset = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < read; i++)
            {
                final char ch = buffer[i];
                if (cr)
                {
                    // Last character was CR.
                    switch (ch)
                    {
                        case '\n':
                            // Found a CRLF.
                            if (i != 0)
                            {
                                line.append(buffer, offset, i - 1 - offset);
                            }

                            // Next line starts at the next character.
                            offset = i + 1;

                            lines.add(line.toString());
                            line = new StringBuilder();

                            cr = false;
                            break;
                        case '\r':
                            break;
                        default:
                            cr = false;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else if (ch == '\r')
                {
                    cr = true;
                }
            }

            // Append remaining characters to the next line.
            line.append(buffer, offset, read - offset);
        }

        return lines.poll();
    }
}
```

Initially, the reader passed some naive tests. However, once I started altering the buffer size, I noticed that some tests failed.

```java
@Test
void readLine() throws IOException
{
    final String[] lines = new String[]{"foo bar", "baz", ""};
    final String str = Stream.of(lines).collect(joining("\r\n"));
    final Collection<Executable> assertions = new LinkedList<>();

    for (int bufferSize = 1; bufferSize <= 10; bufferSize++)
    {
        final LineReader reader = new LineReader(new StringReader(str),
                bufferSize);
        assertions.add(() ->
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
            {
                assertEquals(lines[i], reader.readLine());
            }

            assertNull(reader.readLine());
        });
    }

    assertAll(assertions);
}
```

More specifically, the equality assertion only fails when the buffer size is set to 1, 2, 4 or 8. And even stranger, the error messages are all blank.

```
Multiple Failures (4 failures)
>
>
>
>
org.opentest4j.MultipleFailuresError: Multiple Failures (4 failures)
>
>
>
>
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertAll.assertAll(AssertAll.java:80)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertAll.assertAll(AssertAll.java:54)
...
```

I can't wrap my head around this.

Comment: Your own solution is too complex. You don't need the `char[] buffer` (there's already a buffer in `BufferedReader`, don't duplicate functionality for no reason) or your queue. You just need the `BufferedReader` and the `StringBuilder` to build the line, with the `StringBuilder` being a local variable of your own `readLine()`. The logic stays the same.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'd really like to understand why this particular piece of code doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Run it through a debugger? Some logic error due to the unneeded buffer. A working solution can be achieved with a static method of a few lines, so debugging your implementation is not very appealing to me.

Answer (score 0):

So it turned out that I've been wrongly appending a CR when it's the last character in the buffer, even though it is followed by a LF. The redundant CR also caused the error messages to be truncated weirdly in my console output. Below is the working method:

```java
String readLine() throws IOException
{
    while (lines.peek() == null)
    {
        if (line == null)
        {
            break;
        }

        final int read = reader.read(buffer);
        if (read == - 1)
        {
            lines.add(line.toString());
            line = null;
            continue;
        }

        int offset = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < read; i++)
        {
            final char ch = buffer[i];

            if (cr)
            {
                if (ch == '\n')
                {
                    if (i != 0)
                    {
                        line.append(buffer, offset, i - 1 - offset);
                    }

                    offset = i + 1;

                    lines.add(line.toString());
                    line = new StringBuilder();

                    cr = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        line.append('\r');
                    }

                    if (ch != '\r')
                    {
                        cr = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (ch == '\r')
            {
                cr = true;
            }
        }

        line.append(buffer, offset, read - offset - (cr ? 1 : 0));
    }

    return lines.poll();
}
```